# Dynamically Resize Controlled TinyMCE React Component

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

Background: we have TinyMCE React inside a few contexts where the parent element is manually resized by the user (resizable modal dialog, etc.) and we want the TinyMCE component to resize appropriately. In older versions, we did this using the resizeTo functionality documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934681/resize-height-tinymce-editor?). However, that no longer seems to be available after the upgrade.

My previous attempt to resolve this involved using a `key` based on concatenating the width and height of the editor with a debounce while it was resizing. Basically, whenever the size changed by enough, I tore down the old component and rendered a new one whose config options included the new size. While this is largely effective, it causes an issue where, when you attempt to edit the field after resizing, it flickers and loses focus initially.

Unfortunately, we are using pixel-based size calculations, so specifying the height in percentages instead of pixels won't work.

What is the new official way to do this? Ideally, there would be some new version of `editor.theme.resizeTo` that we could use instead and dispatch with the key-based solution entirely, but I was unable to find it in any of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the editor in a div which has the calculated height and width, and then set the editor to height and width of 100%.